# String concat behaves in different way

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation, concatenation

Can someone explain the following scenario?

```
String s = "Testing";
s.concat("Java 1");
System.out.println(s);
s = s.concat(" Java 2");
System.out.println(s);
```

The output of the above is:

```
Testing
Testing Java 2
```

Comment: You should read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29) of the method. That is where the contract and behavious of the method is explained.

Comment: The first statement is similar to writing only: `42 + 42;` while the second one is similar to doing something like: `int s = 42 + 42;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because, in Java `String` object is `immutable` (value stored in the object cannot be changed). When you perform operations such as `concat` or `replace`, internally a new object is created to hold the result.

Answer (score 3):

When you said

```
String s = "Testing";
s.concat("Java 1"); // this returns a new String which is "TestingJava 1"
System.out.println(s);
```

The `concat` method produced a **new** `String` which was not stored by your program. The reason for returning new `String` shows **immutable** behaviour of `String` class in java.

For mutable string operations you can use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`

Answer (score 1):

String.concat returns concatinated string which you ignored, try this

```
String s = "Testing";
s = s.concat("Java 1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [**docs:**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29)

> the length of the argument string is 0, then this String object is returned. Otherwise, a new String object is created, representing a character sequence that is the concatenation of the character sequence represented by this String object and the character sequence represented by the argument string.

your `s.concat("Java 1");`  returning a new `string`

Answer (score 1):

1) In the first you are not assign s a new value.
2) Second time you are assigning s a new value like `s = s.concat(" Java 2");`